# JavaScript pie chart functions and callbacks displaying only last elements in database

Tags: javascript, google-pie-chart

I am trying to create dynamic number of pie charts depending on how many question I have in my quiz but, the function that creates the chart is in for loop only 1 pie chart is displayed with data which are last in database.

```
var l = 0;
for (var j in quizs[i].quests) {
if (val == quizs[i].quests[j]["quizId"]) {
    l = l + 1;
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    alert("before++" + quizs[i].quests[j]["question"]);

    function drawChart() {

        alert("in++" + quizs[i].quests[j]["question"]);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work', 11],
            ['Eat', 2],
            ['Commute', 2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(l));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
}
```

for example `alert("in++" + quizs[i].quests[j]["question"]);` is the last element in database, any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` must support only one callback. You should put your loop inside of the callback instead of trying to load a new Google Charts API for each loop iteration:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => {
  var l = 0;
  for (var j in quizs[i].quests) {
    if (val == quizs[i].quests[j]["quizId"]) {
      l = l + 1;
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2],
        ['Commute', 2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(l));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  }
});

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```